# Python Print Mixup

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous

I am trying to make a flask request logging module for my project. It has a simple log() function. It isn't a complicated function it just takes the request and response from @app.after_request and prints the time and the status code and some other stuff with colors and things like that.

I expected that evry line is printed under another but sometimes when there are multiple requests coming in at the same time there are some wierd mixups like in the image. [image].

Comment: That's normal for any multi-threading environment when two threads try to output at the same time.  You need some kind of protection around your logging statements to make sure only one thread runs them at a time.

Comment: @MarkRansom do u have some kind of solution to this?

Comment: If I did I'd leave an answer instead of a comment.  I was hoping the term "protection" would spur you to do more research on threading primitives.  I've never had occasion to do it myself, at least not in Python.

Comment: Take a look at *threading.Lock* [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score -2):

You can just make it so that every time a request or response is taken you add a `+'\n'` to it so that there is always a new line for the next time. If you are using print() function you can do print(request_thingy_var + '\n') in the loop. If the problem does lie in there being multiple requests at the same time, use an if statement where if there is a request being processed currently, then delay the other request(s) until the current one is done.

Comment: This would not fix the issue as the problem lies with multiple requests coming in at the same time

Comment: sorry I just fixed my answer